# Using Substring and IndexOf methods in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Dim Op1 As String
Dim Op2 As String
Dim operatore As String
operatore = ComboBox1.Value
Op1 = operatore.Substring(0, operatore.IndexOf("<")).Trim()
Op2 = operatore.Split(">")(1)
```

When I compile, I get the error: "Qualifier not valid" refered to variable "operatore". How can I fix it?

Comment: VBA is not VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerning VBA, and not VB.Net, then you need `Split()` to refer the splitted array and `OLEObjects()` to refer to the OLEObjects.

This compiles and returns what you probably need:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()

    Dim Op1 As String
    Dim Op2 As String
    Dim operatore As String

    operatore = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
    Op1 = Split(operatore, "<")(0)
    Op2 = Split(operatore, ">")(1)

End Sub
```

In VBA `IndexOf` does not exist. It is only in VB.NET - [MSDN IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might save someone some time in the future:

```vb
    ' indexof
    Dim positionInPath As Integer
    positionInPath = InStr("C:\Users\2200522\Documents\", "2200522") ' returns 10
    ' C:\Users\2200522\Documents\
    ' ^^^      ^      
    ' 123      10     
    
    ' substring 
    Dim newPath As String
    newPath = Left("C:\Users\2200522\Documents\", 10) ' returns "C:\Users\2"
```